# How can I avoid recursion in Maximum tip calculator?

Tags: python, algorithm

a,b represent tips for worker a and b for each order.
n is the number of orders 
x is the number of orders worker a can handle
y is the number of orders worker b can handle

This is the code I'm using:

```
def maxTip(self, a, b, n, x, y):
    idx=[[],[],[]]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]>b[i]:
            idx[0].append(i)
        elif b[i]>a[i]:
            idx[1].append(i)
        else:
            idx[2].append(i)
    def findSum(arr):
        sum1=0
        sum2=0
    
        for index in idx[0]:
            sum1+=a[index]
            
        for index in idx[1]:
            sum2+=b[index]
        return sum1+sum2
    
    i=0
    while len(idx[0])<x:
        idx[0].append(idx[2][i])
        i+=1
    while len(idx[1])<y and i<len(idx[2]):
        idx[1].append(idx[2][i])
        i+=1
    return(findSum(idx))
```

I am searching through ith index of both lists at the same time to find the relative maximum at that index. If the ith element of `a` is greater than the ith element of `b` then that element gets appended to the first subarray of the array defined at the beginning. Similarly, it is done for the larger element of `b`. The remaining or the equal values are appended to the third sublist. When I need to find the maximum tip, I go through a loop till `x` to add the elements of the third subarray to the first subarray. When the length is `x`, I add the rest of the elements to the next subarray. Then I find the sum. It works with some inputs. But it fails most of the time.

I have recently started learning algorithms so this might be a very stupid question for many.

Example:

```
n=5 
x=3 
y=3 
a=[1,2,3,4,5] 
b=[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Here the maximum sum would be 21. Worker a will take orders 3,4,5 and worker b will take order 1,2. Worker a will get (3+4+5)=12 amount and worker b will get (5+4)=9 and 12+9=21.

What should I do to find the correct output for:

```
n=7
x=3
y=4
a=[8, 7, 5, 9, 6, 6, 8]
b=[1, 7, 5, 1, 2, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Extremely complicated description to read, along with non-descriptive variables. Please add some examples.

Comment: In `for i in range(len(a))` you append to idx[0] & idx[1] without taking into account the consstraint on their max lengths (i.e. x, y).  This causes it to be incorrect in the simple case of: `x = 1; y = 1; a = [10, 100]; b = [1, 1];` where your software gives an answer of 110 rather than the correct answer of 101.

Comment: @DarrlG Thanks for pointing that out. Although it works for some more cases, it is not working for all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Description**

> Given two arrays of size N and two integers X and Y indicating the maximum number of elements, one can pick from array A and array B respectively.
> At each ith turn, either A[i] or B[i] can be picked. The task is to make the selection that results in the maximum possible sum.
> Note: It is guaranteed that (X + Y) ≥ N.

**Posted Code**

Provides incorrect answers for a simple solution such as:

```
x, y = 1, 1
a = [10, 100]
b = [1, 1]
n = 2
print(Solution().maxTip(a, b, n, x, y))
# Outputs: 110
```

*Error*: the correct answer is 101 (not 110)

**Better Solution**

Translating to Python the approach from [Maximum sum by picking elements from two arrays in order](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-by-picking-elements-from-two-arrays-in-order/) which are in C++, and JavaScript

Steps:

1. Sort the element pairs according to the absolute difference i.e. |A[i] – B[i]| in decreasing order.
2. Compare A[i] and B[i] value, the one which is greater adds that value to the sum.
3. Decrement X by one if the element is chosen from A[i] else decrement Y by one.
4. If X is out or Y is out add min(A[i], B[i]) to sum

*Code*

```
class Solution:
    def maxTip(self, a, b, n, x, y):
        """
        : a   - can pick either from array a
        : b     or array b on each turn
        : n   - length of a & b
        : x   - number of times can pick from a
        : y   - number of times can pick from b
        """
        # Step 1: Sort the element pairs according to the absolute differenc
        ab_pairs = sorted([p for p in zip(a, b)],               # sequence of a, b pairs formed by zip(a, b)
                          key = lambda kv: abs(kv[0] - kv[1]),  # sorting pairs based upon absolute difference
                          reverse = True)                       # sort in non-ascending order
        tsum = 0
        for ai, bi in ab_pairs:
            if ai > bi and x > 0:    # 2. Compare A[i] and B[i] value,
                tsum += ai           #    the one which is greater adds that value to the sum.
                x -= 1               # 3. Decrement X by one if the element is chosen from A[i]
            elif bi > ai and y > 0:  # 2. Compare A[i] and B[i] value,
                tsum += bi           #    the one which is greater adds that value to the sum.
                y -= 1               # 3. else decrement Y by one.
            else:
                tsum += min(ai, bi)  # 4. If x is out or y is out add min(A[i], B[i]) to sum

        return tsum
```

*Test*

```
n=7
x=3
y=4
a=[8, 7, 5, 9, 6, 6, 8]
b=[1, 7, 5, 1, 2, 3, 9]
print(Solution().maxTip(a, b, n, x, y)
# Output: 47
```